# What is a "port", from the POV of MacPorts?

Tags: port, macports

I am trying to install Pandas for Python on my Mac. I installed Xcode, then MacPorts based on another SO post, then typed the command `sudo port install py27-pandas`.

1. What exactly is a "port"? I've read the definition of it and it is a type of "Software Construct" (not sure what that means). From reading the documentation for MacPorts, MacPorts "Installs automatically any required support software, known as dependencies, for a given port." In my case, would Pandas be the "port"? If so, why does MacPorts install over 50 dependencies when the Pandas documentation cite only three dependencies?
2. How exactly do I use MacPorts? I currently use the Terminal to access Python. Do I do something different now that Pandas was installed through MacPorts? Or is MacPorts basically just an "installer", and I go through the same process to use Python?

Comment: I think macports takes its name from the idea that the software is a "ported version" - not that they are necessarily ported but because of the "ease of installation" with dependancies resolved etc the software appears to be more or less native to mac like a pkg. Just treat it as an installer like easy_install or more appropriately apt-get et-al

Answer (score 0):

This question might be more appropriate for the Programming SE group.  Not sure.  I'll try to answer.  My apologies if I go over things that are already obvious.

I think that MacPorts may have adapted a common use of "port" to mean something slightly different.

To port a piece of software is to adapt it to a new software environment--such as an operating system.  For example, someone might take a piece of software that was originally written for Windows, and "port" it to MacOS.  Sometimes this is easy, involving changing a few lines of source code, and sometimes it involves modifying many lines of code.  Sometimes you have to find extra pieces of software (sometimes called "libraries") to take the place of what was automatically provided in the other operating system.  More generally, what I meant by "software environment" could be any piece of software that people use as a building block for writing other software.  For example, C# is a programming language that's similar to the Java programming language many respects.  Someone might take software that was written in C# and rewrite it in Java.  That's "porting" the software.

Once software is ported, the new version of the software is called a port.

Much of the software available through MacPorts was ported in the above sense--i.e. it was modified to run in MacOS, because it was originally written for another operating system.  In some cases what was needed to port the software was pretty minimal, because the software was written for Unix or Linux, and OS X is Unix underneath the normal interface.  It wouldn't surprise me if some of the software in MacPorts wasn't ported at all--it was originally written for MacOS.  So that would be one way that MacPorts extends the meaning of "port".

Remember what I said above about software making use of other software, such as libraries?  If you install a piece of software, it might need other software in order to run.  The first software has "dependencies" on other software.  One of the things that MacPorts does is to keep track of that.  It installs the extra software when you ask for the first piece of software.

I don't know what Pandas is.  Can't help you about how to use it.  However about the 50 depencies: It may be that Pandas immediately depends on 3 other pieces of software, but *they* depend on other software, which depends on other software, etc., and pretty soon you get 50 dependencies.

(There's also a use of "port" to refer to hardware or software that functions as something that you can send and receive data to/from.  These days this use of the term usually comes up with programming concerning computer networking, seems to me.)